# Trim is not doing it

Tags: powershell

I am building a script that will `Test-Connection` the local gateway and a website.  To get the active gateway I use:

```
$GateWay = (Get-wmiObject Win32_networkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPEnabled}).DefaultIPGateway
```

This works fine, but it adds two spaces to the outcome.  I have used `Trim()` to get them away, but using `.length`, that does not do the job and it breaks in the next lines of my script.  So, stuck here..

Here the code I use to test:

```
Clear-host
$Gateway = [String](Get-wmiObject Win32_networkAdapterConfiguration | ?{$_.IPEnabled}).DefaultIPGateway
$GateWay.Length
$GateWay.Trim()
$GateWay.Length
```

Answer (score 3):

`Trim()` doesn't modify the string, it *returns a modified copy*.

Try this:

```
$GateWay = $GateWay.Trim()
```

Comment: Thank you Jonathon.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon.
I tried this and still receive error
I also had to add [string] in front of the (Get-wmiObject..)
And now it is working.  So again, thank you!